# Get a List instead of a Simple Field Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, list

I'm working with Entity Framework 4.0.

In my project I need to get and set values to/from the properties.
Everything works fine but I have to get now a **List** and also set a **List** of any type..
So I have no Idea how to do that.

What it looks like for a simple field property (Original from code, *that works*):

```
businnesObject.GetType().GetProperty(entityBase.GetType().Name).SetValue(businnesObject, entityBase, null);
```

And what I exactly need is something like that (*doesnt work*):

```
EntityBase mainEntity = (EntityBase)navigationPropertyAnzeigeUserControl.SelectedObject;
List<Object> collection = (List<Object>)businnesObject.GetType().GetProperty(mainEntity.GetType().Name).GetValue(businnesObject, null);
collection.Add(mainEntity);
businnesObject.GetType().GetProperty(mainEntity.GetType().Name).SetValue(businnesObject, collection, null);
```

Maybe someone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok did it..

```
mainEntity = (EntityBase)navigationPropertyAnzeigeUserControl.SelectedObject;
                    IEnumerable<object> collection = (IEnumerable<object>)businnesObject.GetType().GetProperty("Positionen").GetValue(businnesObject, null);
                    List<object> test = collection.ToList();
                    test.Add(mainEntity);
                    businnesObject.GetType().GetProperty(LoescheAlleZeichenNachEinemGewissenZeichen(mainEntity.GetType().Name, '_')).SetValue(businnesObject, collection, null);
```